# Distribution/expected length of the shortest path in infinite random geometric graphs

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, density-function, asymptotics, graph-theory

Consider an infinite random geometric graph $G(\rho,d)$ in which vertices are uniformly and independently scattered over the 2D plane with density $\rho$ and edges connect the vertices that are closer than $d$.

What is the distribution/expected value of the  length of the shortest path from a vertex $v_0$ to another vertex $v_1$ which is $k$ hops faraway?

***Note:***

We know that the length of the edges follow the following PDF:

$$
f(l)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2 l}{d^2} \;\quad l \le d \\
0 \qquad\; l > d
\end{cases}
$$

However, I guess the expected length of the shortest path is not simply $k \times$ the expected length of the edges because in a shortest path longer edges are more likely to be chosen, right?

Comment: How do we know the functional form for the edge length distribution? do you have a derivation/reference?

Comment: I asked the question about a year ago and I can't remember if I copied the formula from somewhere or not. But it seems quite simple. Isn't it the circumference of a circle with radius $l$ over the area of a circle with radius $d$?

Comment: The probability of having a neighbor at distance $l$ grows linearly since the circumference of the circle is $2\pi r$. $\frac{1}{\pi d^2}$ is the normalizing factor to make the probabilities sum to unity.